# trying to return true or false to determine if array is defined or not javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return `true` or `false` to determine if an array is defined or not in JavaScript like this: **[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/rush86999/pen/QyJMPo?editors=0010)**

```
//display function object to display stuff
display(value) {
    //reset display marker to reset the display
    var resetDisplay = false;

    //check the arugments if number set it to display or if an operation highlight the function 
    if (isNaN(value[0]) && value[0] != ".") {
      //highlight selected operation
      $(id[value]).css("padding", "5px");
      //if clear pressed set display to zero
      if (value == "=") {
        $("#display").text("0");
      }

      //set reset display to true
      resetDisplay = true;

    } else {
      //display the value by concatenating it unless reset display is set to true after operation pressed
      if (resetDisplay = true) {
        $("#display").text(value);
        //reset the display to not true to continue to concatenate
        resetDisplay = false;
      } else {
        //continue to concatenate display
        $("display").text($("#display").text().concat(value));
        console.log($("#display").text().concat(value));
      }
    }

    //helper object that correlates with #id for each button
    var id = {
      "+": "#add",
      "-": "#subtract",
      "*": "#multiply",
      "/": "#divide",
      "=": "#equals",
      "1": "#one",
      "2": "#two",
      "3": "#three",
      "4": "#four",
      "5": "#five",
      "6": "#six",
      "7": "#seven",
      "8": "#eight",
      "9": "#nine",
      "0": "#zero",
      ".": "#point"
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out this error at `$(id[value]).css('padding', '5px');`

> cannot read property of '-' undefined.

I am trying to send in a operation from a button. This function happens within a calculator object.

Comment: What is `id[value]`? You probably need something like `$('#' + id[value])` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (resetDisplay == true)` with the double `==` equality evaluator? is this a typo?

Comment: @Andy if you look at the codepen, you'll notice that he is already using `#` within the id object, so no need for it.

Comment: @AGE your codepen link doesn't work, at least not for me. But regardles, the id-object. Is not defined when you call it at '$(id[value])'

Comment: @Hydrospanners thanks for noticing the codepen link is broken, it's fixed now.

Comment: I'm seeing you pass the keypress as a string. You're grabbing in in your `press` function with `this.pressed = arguments[0];`. This is fine, but then you do `this.pressed[0]`, even though `this.pressed` is a string and not an array.

Comment: Also, Hydrospanners was spot-on. You can define and use functions in any order, but variable declarations _must_ come before you can use them. You're calling `id` _before_ you declare it.

Comment: @RushiParikh you still need to define the id-array earlier in display. That's why you get undefined error. There is no array to index yourself in at that point. I changed it in your codepen and i reach another error. So i'm sure that is what's causing your "cannot read property of '-' undefined." error

Comment: @Hydrospanners keep in mind Rushi Parikh (the one who asked the question) was the one who provided the CodePen, but yes ultimately you are correct.

Comment: @AGE Changed my @-direction sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is with the way you are checking for your `resetDisplay` variable. By using the `=` operator, you are essentially assigning `true` to `resetDisplay` rather than checking for `true`.

You can check for `true` very easily, either by identity (strict equality) `===` or by simply doing the below with `if(variableName)` which should check for `true` regardless.

```
if (resetDisplay) {
    $("#display").text(value);
    //reset the display to not true to continue to concatenate
    resetDisplay = false;
}
```

In terms if your `$(id[value])` you need to be sure that `id` is declared **before** it is used. So make sure you fix that by declaring it like so:

```
//display function object to display stuff
display(value) {
  //reset display marker to reset the display
  var resetDisplay = false,
      id = { //helper object that correlates with #id for each button
        "+": "#add",
        "-": "#subtract",
        "*": "#multiply",
        "/": "#divide",
        "=": "#equals",
        "1": "#one",
        "2": "#two",
        "3": "#three",
        "4": "#four",
        "5": "#five",
        "6": "#six",
        "7": "#seven",
        "8": "#eight",
        "9": "#nine",
        "0": "#zero",
        ".": "#point"
      };

  //check the arugments if number set it to display or if an operation highlight the function 
  if (isNaN(value[0]) && value[0] != ".") {
    //highlight selected operation
    $(id[value]).css("padding", "5px");
    //if clear pressed set display to zero
    if (value == "=") {
      $("#display").text("0");
    }

    //set reset display to true
    resetDisplay = true;

  } else {
    //display the value by concatenating it unless reset display is set to true after operation pressed
    if (resetDisplay) {
      $("#display").text(value);
      //reset the display to not true to continue to concatenate
      resetDisplay = false;
    } else {
      //continue to concatenate display
      $("display").text($("#display").text().concat(value));
      console.log($("#display").text().concat(value));
    }
  }
}
```